# OS X Lion - apache & php setup

Tags: php, apache-http-server, osx-lion

I'm trying to setup the built in apache part of os x to work with php. I've gone through the process of uncommenting the php lines and so forth in the httpd.conf file. However, I can't seem to get the webserver to find any of my files to test. I changed the ListenPort to 3333, since i run https://github.com/37signals/pow on port 80. Like so:

```
 <IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
   Listen 3333
 </IfDefine>
```

And the server seems to respond to 3333 just fine. I also setup the /etc/apache2/users/aaronmcleod.conf to store a virtual host to the ~/Sites folder like so:

```
<Directory "/Users/aaronmcleod/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:3333

<Virtualhost *:3333>
    DocumentRoot /Users/aaronmcleod/Sites
    ServerName aaronmcleod.dev
</Virtualhost>
```

However, when i go to http://localhost:3333/test.php i just receive a 404 error from apache.  Any ideas on what i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if i launch apache under the sharing section of system preferences, i can get to it fine. Though i wonder why it doesn't work when starting the server via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Mac OS X / Mac OS X Server
# The <IfDefine> blocks segregate server-specific directives
# and also directives that only apply when Web Sharing or
# server Web Service (as opposed to other services that need Apache) is on.
# The launchd plist sets appropriate Define parameters.
# Generally, desktop has no vhosts and server does; server has added modules,
# custom virtual hosts are only activated when Web Service is on, and
# default document root and personal web sites at ~username are only
# activated when Web Sharing is on.
```

This means that /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is set up with special xml tags that enable the user to enable or disable modules based on simply if you are a OS X Server or a regular OS X Desktop. Also the configuration is set so that if you go into System Preferences - Sharing - Enable Web Sharing that it configures OS X to load /etc/apache2/other/*.conf which is where you would want to consider placing your whateversite.conf file.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider rolling your own apache if you're doing any really deep development. It's really easy with hombrew : https://github.com/ampt/homebrew